# Turn off Windows Firewall for a single PC in domain?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-firewall, wsus

I have many PC's in domain is there a way to Turn off Windows Firewall remotely for single PC if I'm Domain admin ?
Is there a way to do this without GPO ?

Comment: Why specifically "without GPO"?

Comment: Yea, create a GP and apply it to that computer only.

Answer (score 0):

of course. You can do this from the command line: netsh [-a AliasFile] [-c Context] [-r RemoteMachine] [-u [DomainName ] UserName] [-p Password | *] [Command | -f ScriptFile], use "netsh advfirewall set DomainProfile state off" for the domain